# Return list of row numbers of cells that contain a numeric value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to have a formula that will extract the row number of each numeric value. Also, I do not want to end up with empty cells (or values like "not numeric"). This needs to be a formula, for repeatability. For example, source column looks like this:

```
+--------+
| Foobar |
+--------+
| Foobar |
+--------+
| 123    |
+--------+
| 123    |
+--------+
| Foobar |
+--------+
| 123    |
+--------+
```

I want to end up with:

```
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
| 4 |
+---+
| 6 |
+---+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=FILTER(ROW(A1:A6),ISNUMBER(A1:A6))` if it starts in the first row

Else `=TOCOL(SEQUENCE(ROWS(C2:C9))/C2:C9^0,2)`

Comment: Why not `*C2:C9^0`? It results in the same, right?

Comment: @VBasic2008 that would be the same. The idea is that `C2:C9^0` returns `1` for numerical values, but returns an error in case of text. The TOCOL filters out the errors with the `2` argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try `FILTER()` with `ISNUMBER()`.

```
=FILTER(A2:A7,ISNUMBER(B2:B7))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, the row numbers were only for illustrative purposes, I do not actually have these as cells available. :-( I understand that this is confusing, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Do you want relative or absolute row number? For absolute row number try =FILTER(ROW(A1:A6),ISNUMBER(A1:A6)) where A1:A6 is your dataset

Comment: @Ambidex Then please use `=FILTER(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B7)),ISNUMBER(B2:B7))`.

Answer (score 1):

### Get Row Indexes of Numbers in Column

```
=LET(data,A2:A11,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),ISNUMBER(data)))
```

[image]